# How do I combine multiple python regex arguments?

Tags: python, regex, filter

I need to filter out the following things from a list:

```
^[^\w ]$

'^\n( )*$' (\n at the beginning followed by spaces)

'^\n( )*\n$' (\n at both ends with spaces)

'^[]$' (space alone)
```

how can I combine them into a single expression?

Comment: can you add possible output?

Comment: use or operator `|`. plus, space alone is simply `^ $`. Make sure you don't mean `^\s$` which is any whitespace character

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
r1 ='^[^\w ]'
r2 ='^\n( )*'
r3= '^\n( )*\n'
r4 = '^\n( )*\n'
string="(\n at the beginning followed by spaces)"
generic_re = re.compile("(%s|%s|%s|%s)" % (r1, r2, r3, r4)).findall(string)
```